# Where to put jar file in ruby on rails project?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, applet

I've created a Java Applet that reads data from a serial connected device. Now i need to add the Java Applet (the .jar library) into my Ruby on Rails application but in which directory do i put the used libraries so that i can access them from the applet tag? I've tried putting the jar archives into the same directory of the views but this doesn't really seem to work.

My applet tag looks like this in my ruby view (HAML):

```
%applet{:'id' => "equinelife_applet", :name => "equinelife_applet", :archive => "datareader.jar", :code => "com.reader", :width => "0", :height => "0", :mayscript => "true"}
 %param{:name => "separate_jvm", :value => "true"}
```

So according to me the only thing that has to change is the archive path to the datareader.jar file? But where do i put my jar file...

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

In the `public` folder, where directly-accessible files (like `index.html`) go.

Answer (score 2):

You can put in anywhere in /public for example in

```
public/java/file.jar
```

so you can access it by link

```
http://domain.com/java/file.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way is to put such files in `vendor/assets` (only for Rails with asset_pipeline)